# Encrypt the same data with AES using strong but different passwords

Tags: encryption, aes

I'm going to send the same piece of data encrypted with AES using strong but different passwords several time through the Internet. Is it secure or I should change something in data each time?

Comment: AES in most common mode adds random data at the beggining so you don't have to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, you don't need to change data. AES, and any modern, secure cipher in a proper mode of operation will output ciphertext indistinguishable from random data. There *are* some caveats if you are attempting to implement a cryptosystem on your own, using the raw crypto primitives, in which case you would need to add the right type of random data in the right place (such as an IV), but if you are using a good implementation in the right mode (at minimum, CBC), there is nothing to worry about. You should use something established like GnuPG. The ciphertext will be different if the key is different at all. If that wasn't secure, then TLS would be more badly broken than it is!

However, although this is *cryptographically* secure, your specific threat model may still not allow you to do this safely. For example, the specific file sizes or the times they are uploaded by you may reveal that they contain the same data. Whether or not this is acceptable is up to you.